# Generic Parameter. How to pass in to a constructor and then add to a list?

Tags: c#, generics

I Have a class

```
class ExpiryList
{
    protected ConcurrentDictionary <GenericType, DateTime> m_list;

    ExpiryList(GenericType obj, DateTime expiryDate)
    {
        m_list.AddOrUpdate(obj, expiryDate, (x, y) => { return expiryDate; });
    }
}
```

And i am wondering how to implement this? I need a way to create an instance of this class that stores either int, string, String, double etc... into the GenericType variable.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your class generic:

```
class ExpiryList<TAnyType>
{
    protected ConcurrentDictionary <TAnyType, DateTime> m_list;

    ExpiryList(TAnyType obj, DateTime expiryDate)
    {
        m_list.AddOrUpdate(obj, expiryDate, (x, y) => { return expiryDate; });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to create a generic class:

```
public class ExpiryList<T>
```